# Change of variable for Lebesegue Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $G$ be an absolutely continuous function, $G:[a,b] \rightarrow [c,d]$ and $f \geq 0$ a Lebesegue measurable function in $[c,d]$. I managed to prove that if $f$ is just Borel measurable it holds $$\int_c^d f(t)dt= \int_a^b f(G(\tau) |G'(t)| d\tau$$

I know that every Lebesgue measurable function is a.e. equal to a Borel function so I think from that I can extend the theorem.

Now I am asked to do the following: Let $h$ be a function such that $h=0$ a.e. on $[c,d]$.  Consider the sets $H=\lbrace{ \tau \in [a,b] : |G'(\tau) >0\rbrace}$ and $N \subset [c,d]$ such that $\lambda(N)=0$. Prove that $\lambda(G^{-1}(N) \cap H)=0$. Verify that this means that the function $(h\circ G )|G'|=0$ almost everywhere in $[a,b]$.

Comment: See this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/838804/properties-of-absolutely-continuous-functions/840740#840740

Comment: Sorry, I do not understood you comment. What do you mean?

Comment: I don't know if this is right but for the theorem of change of variables between measures I have that I can consider a Borel measure $\mu (E)=\int_E G' d\lambda $ for each $E \in \mathbb{B}([a,b])$. Then for each $E' \in \mathbb{B}([c,d])$ we have $\mu (G^{-1}(E'))=\lambda (E')$. Now $\lambda(G^{-1}(N) \cap H) \leq \lambda(G^{-1}(N))=\lambda(N)=0$.